# Notificaciones push FCM no llegan con el app cerrada

Tags: java, android, firebase

Cuando el app está abierta o detrás de escena, todo bien, llegan las notificaciones, pero cuando el app está cerrada, llega solo en algunos celulares.

Por ejemplo, en un Sony llega muy bien cuando el app está cerrada, pero en un Huawei Y6 no llega si el app está cerrada.

Código:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        //Getting registration token
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

       // SharedPreferences.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setString(SPKeys.Keys.API_TOKEN,refreshedToken);
        //Displaying token on logcat
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.handleIntent(intent);
        try {
            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "handleIntent: " + intent.getExtras().toString());

                if (!isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                    String title = intent.getExtras().get("gcm.notification.title").toString();
                    String body = intent.getExtras().get("gcm.notification.body").toString();
                    String url = intent.getExtras().get("URL").toString();


                    sendNotification(title, body, url);
                } else {
                    Utility.PUSH_NOTIFICATIONMESSAGE = intent.getExtras().get("URL").toString();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: en handle intent " + Utility.PUSH_NOTIFICATIONMESSAGE);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: en catch " + Utility.PUSH_NOTIFICATIONMESSAGE);
        }
    }


    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String tittle, String urlIMG) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
        if (urlIMG == null && urlIMG.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        } else {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlIMG);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        }

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        final  NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        /*notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));*/
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp);
        notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(tittle);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(messageBody);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    }


    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }
}
```

y en mi Manifest:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@android:color/transparent" />

    <!-- Firebase Notifications -->
    <service android:name=".notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".notification.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio no olvides realizar el [tour]. No esta de mas leer [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es importante aclarar que las Push Notifications de [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=es-419) deben llegar aún si la aplicación se encuentra cerrada.

Si tu implementación es correcta y la lectura de los datos del Payload debe ser correcta ya que [la aplicación cliente es responsable de procesar y generar el mensaje a partir de los datos](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?hl=es-419).

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // ...

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
            // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
            scheduleJob();
        } else {
            // Handle message within 10 seconds
            handleNow();
        }

    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
```

Los casos en los cuales los usuarios reportan que no reciben las notificaciones son:

No tienen habilitada la recepción de notificaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En pantalla cerrada/apagada tienes habilitado no mostrar notificaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un Huawei Y6 II y también pasé por esto. El sistema de Huawei por defecto no permite que las aplicaciones manden notificaciones, para esto debes habilitarlas desde `Gestor del teléfono > Centro de notificaciones` y ahí seleccionra tu app y habilitar las notificaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supuestamente existe un método para habilitarlas por código ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45631400/2711585)) pero no lo he probado.